# unable get the return value in the Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Below is my code that I used to call a function that returns a value after fetching from the Firebase ref.

```
let original = Promise.resolve(this.contactService.fetchContact(contact));
    original.then(function(value){
      console.log("original value: " + value);//point 2
    });
```

the Firebase fetching function is as below:

```
fetchContact(name){
    //fetch contact object from name
    let contactObj = this.database.ref('path').orderByChild('name').equalTo(name).once('value').then(response=>{
        console.log(response.val());//Point 1
        return response.val();
    });
  }
```

The problem is, in the comment Point 1, I get the desired value as the output. But as I have returned the same to the Promise, I want it to be returned as the response in the comment Point 2. What I get is `undefined` in the comment Point 2

This is not the same as that of the Ajax call or Http Requests. This is within the local files.
Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to `return contactObj;` in the `fetchContact` function?

Comment: You don't need to wrap the result of `fetchContact` in yet another `Promise.resolve`. *If* you return the promise (`contactObj`) from `fetchContact`, a simple `fetchContact().then(...)` will do.

Comment: Thanks for the neat idea. It worked @deceze :)